# A inhomogeneous heat equation with mixed conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve the given problem:

\begin{equation}
u_t-u_{xx}=2 \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<1, t>0 \\
u(0,t)=0, \ \ u_x(1,t)=1, \ \ \ t>0\\
u(x,0)=-x^2, \ \ \ \ 0<x<1
\end{equation}

but I am not sure I have done it correctly. This is what I did:

**Step 1. Homogenize, by solving the stationary problem $u_t=0$:**

\begin{equation}
-u_{xx}=2 \rightarrow u(x)-x^2+Cx+D \\
I.C. give \rightarrow u(x)=-x^2+3x
\end{equation}

The homogenized PDE is now:

\begin{equation}
u_t-u_{xx}=0 \ \ \ \ \ 0<x<1, t>0 \\
u(0,t)=0, \ \ u_x(1,t)=1, \ \ \ t>0\\
u(x,0)=-x^2+x^2-3x \rightarrow u(x,0)=-3x, \ \ \ \ 0<x<1
\end{equation}

**Step 2. Solve the homogenous PDE.**

Since we have mixed conditions, we need to look for a linear combination of $u(x)=A\sin\lambda x+B\cos\lambda x$ which satisfies the I.C.

We get:

\begin{equation}
u(x)=A\sin\lambda x+ B\cos\lambda x \rightarrow \ \ IC: u(0)=0 \rightarrow u(x)=A\sin\lambda x\\
u(x)=A\sin\lambda x, \rightarrow IC2: u'(1)=1,\ \ \ u'(x)= \lambda A\cos\lambda x \rightarrow 1=\lambda A\cos\lambda \rightarrow A=\frac{1}{\lambda\cos\lambda}\\
u(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda\cos\lambda}\sin\lambda x
\end{equation}

So now we have a first candidate of the function

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u(t)
\end{equation}

We find out u(t) by plugging this in the PDE, where each of the following is:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u(t)\\
u_{xx}(x,t)=-\frac{\lambda^2\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u(t)\\
u_t(x,t)=\frac{\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u_t
\end{equation}

By inserting eacah part in the homogenized PDE we get:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u_t+\frac{\lambda^2\sin\lambda x}{\lambda\cos\lambda}u(t)=0\\
u(t)=C_ne^{-\lambda^2t}
\end{equation}

**Step 3. Find the coefficients**

So since we now have the full form of $u(x,t)$, we can use the third IC for the homogenized problem, $u(x,0)=-3x$ and use the Fourier series method to find the coefficient:

\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=-3x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{C_n}{\lambda\cos\lambda}\sin\lambda xe^0
\end{equation}

This coefficient we find by using the Fourier series form for $\beta_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lu(x,0)\sin\lambda xdx$. Here we have both $u(x,0)=-3x$ and $L=1$ so we obtain that $\frac{C_n}{\lambda\cos\lambda}=\beta_n$: This is the famous "Fourier trick" used to find the coefficients of the heat, Laplace and wave equations. So this "trick" gives:

\begin{equation}
\frac{C_n}{\lambda\cos\lambda}=2\int_0^1(-3x)\sin\lambda xdx
\end{equation}

Solving the L.H.S we get $-\frac{\cos\lambda}{\lambda}$, so the equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\frac{C_n}{\lambda\cos\lambda}=-\frac{\cos\lambda}{\lambda}
\end{equation}

Hence,

$C_n=-\cos^2\lambda$

Since the system was inhomogenous, we need to add the function $u(x,0)=-3x$

This gives the final form of $u(x,t)$

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=-3x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\lambda}{\lambda}\sin\lambda x e^{-\lambda^2 t}
\end{equation}

But I am not sure about the last step, to add the function $u(x,0)=-3x$. Is it right to do, or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is to add

$u(x)=-x^2+3x$ to the  solution of the homogeneous problem.

That is

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\pi} {n\pi}\sin n\pi x e^{-(n\pi)^2 t}\bigg]-x^2+3x)
\end{equation}

which gives

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=-x^2+3x+\bigg[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\pi}{n\pi}\sin n\pi x e^{-(n\pi)^2 t}\bigg]
\end{equation}

This satisfies the non-homogeneous solution, giving, when inserted in the PDE with $n=1$

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[-x^2+3x+e^{-(n\pi)^2 t} \cos n\pi \frac{\sin n\pi x}{n\pi}\bigg]-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\bigg[-x^2+3x+e^{-(n\pi)^2t} \cos n\pi\frac{\sin n\pi x}{n\pi}\bigg]=2\\
-e^{-(n\pi)^2 t} n\pi \cos n\pi \sin n\pi x - \bigg[-e^{-(n\pi)^2 t } n\pi \cos n\pi \sin n\pi x-2\bigg]=2\\
2=2
\end{equation}

Comment: You're looking like a pro at these problems. Did you check $u_x(1,t)=1$? That seems to be a tough one to check.

Comment: No, I am not sure on that one.

Comment: Maybe you could check my solution to see if it satisfies all of the required conditions.

Comment: Thanks Disintegration.  To do that, I would need the whole solution, not only $−2x^2+x$. Or is the rest the same as mine?

Comment: @Luther415Hz : How do your values of $\lambda$ depend on the sum index $n$?

Comment: $\lambda=n\pi$, since $L=1$

Answer (score 2):

The problem in question is
$$
      u_t-u_{xx}=2 \\
      u(0,t)=0,\; u_x(1,t)=1 \\
      u(x,0)=-x^2
$$
This needs to be transformed to a homogeneous problem in order for separation of variables to work. One way to do this is to add a function $f(x)$ to $u$ so that the differential equation and endpoint conditions are homogeneous. That requires finding a function $f$ to satisfy the following:
$$
             (u+f)_t-(u+f)_{xx}=0 \implies f''(x)=2 \\
             u(0,t)+f(0)=0 \implies f(0)=0 \\
             u_x(1,t)+f'(1)=0 \implies f'(1)=-1
$$

$f(x)=x^2-3x$ is such a solution. (Thank you @Luthier415Hz for pointing out my errors and confusion about this.)

The original problem for $u$ has now been transformed to a problem in $v=u+f$ that satisfies the following:
$$
           v_t=v_{xx} \\
           v(0,t)=0,\;\; v_x(1,t)=0, \\
           v(x,0) = -3x.
$$
Separation of variables can be used to directly solve this problem because of the homogenous endpoint conditions.

The desired solution is $u=v-f$. To solve for $v$ using separation of variables, assume $v(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$. This will work because of the homogeneous endpoint conditions in $x$:
$$
          \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\lambda = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} \\
               X(0)=0,\;\; X'(1)=0.
$$
The $X$ equation has solutions that are determined only up to a constant $C$:
$$
           X_n(x) = C_n\sin((n+1/2)\pi x),\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding eigenvalue parameter $\lambda$ is
$$
           \lambda_n = -(n+1/2)^2\pi^2,\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
And the corresponding solution $T_n$ is any constant multiple of
$$
            T_n(t) = \exp(-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t)
$$
This leads to the general solution for $v$:
$$
          v(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n \exp(-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x).
$$
The constants $C_n$ are determined by the condition $v(x,0)=-3x$, through the orthogonality of the eigenfunctions $\{\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$:
$$
   -3x = v(x,0)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n\sin((n+1/2)\pi x) \\
   \frac{\int_0^1 (-3x)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)dx}{\int_0^1\sin^2((n+1/2)\pi x)dx}= C_n,\;\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
What remains is to determine the constants $C_n$ by evaluating the integrals in the corresponding fractions above. The numerator for $C_n$ is
\begin{align}
   &\int_0^1 (-3x)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)dx \\
  &= \left.\frac{3x\cos((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)\pi}\right|_{0}^{1} \\
  &  - \int_0^1 3\frac{\cos((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)\pi}dx \\
  &= \left.-3\frac{\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}\right|_{x=0}^{1} \\
  &= \frac{3(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}
\end{align}
The denominator for $C_n$ is
\begin{align}
  &\int_0^1\sin^2((n+1/2)\pi x)dx  \\
  & = \left.\frac{-\cos((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)\pi}\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)\right|_{x=0}^{1} \\
 & + \int_0^1\cos^2((n+1/2)^2\pi x)dx \\
 & = \int_0^1\cos^2((n+1/2)^2\pi x)dx
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
   &\int_0^1\sin^2((n+1/2)\pi x)dx \\
   &=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\sin^2((n+1/2)\pi x)+\cos^2((n+1/2)^2\pi x) dx \\
   &=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Finally,
$$
   C_n = \frac{6(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}
$$
The full expression for $v$ is
\begin{align}
    &v(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n \exp(-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x) \\
   &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{6(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}\exp(-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x).
\end{align}
The desired solution is $u=v-f=v-(x^2-3x)$:
\begin{align}
%%   u(x,t)&=v(x,t)-(x^2-3x) \\
  &u(x,t)= -x^2+3x \\
&+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{6(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}\exp(-(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)
\end{align}
NOTE: If I have all the details for this right, I'll be shocked!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz : What does your final sum add up to when you evaluate at $t=0$? Does your final answer satisfy $u(x,0)=-3x$? It looks like it does to me. And what about $u_x(1,t)$? Does that sum equal $1$, as required? You just have to check the conditions of the original problem, one by one. Let me know what you find.

Comment: I found the error, I added an answer. Thanks Disintegrating

Comment: @Luthier415Hz : I've expanded the solution to a full solution above. Everything should check out.

Comment: Great , it looks good, but you didn't calculate the integrals.

Comment: I chcked and it doesnt seem right. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%2832%2F%2827+%CF%80%5E3%29+-+4%2F%283+%CF%80%5E2%29+%2B+x%5E2-x%29*%5Cexp%28-%281%2B1%2F2%29%5E2%5Cpi%5E2+t%29*%5Csin%28%281%2B1%2F2%29%5Cpi+x%29 and

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdt%2832%2F%2827+%CF%80%5E3%29+-+4%2F%283+%CF%80%5E2%29+%2B+x%5E2-x%29*%5Cexp%28-%281%2B1%2F2%29%5E2%5Cpi%5E2+t%29*%5Csin%28%281%2B1%2F2%29%5Cpi+x%29

Comment: In fact, you should use $lambda$ as eigenvalue, because the bounds of x are not trignoometric.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz : The bounds of $x$ are $0$ and $1$. You can't use one $\lambda$ for all of the terms in the sum. These values must depend on $n$. How do they depend on $n$?

Comment: I see your point, to me it was safer to use $\lambda$. However, your solution is still not correct.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz : Take another look at my solution. It is complete with all the coefficients now. This type of answer overwhelms the mathjax system, so I had to do a few unusual alignments to avoid scroll bars that get in the way.

Comment: I have checked, it is correct now. In fact, both our solutions are correct. My method is however much simpler. Why?

Comment: @Disintegration! I have checked your solutions, and I wonder about that integral 

$C_n$ is
\begin{align}
   &\int_0^1 (-3x)\sin((n+1/2)\pi x)dx \\
  &= \left.\frac{3x\cos((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)\pi}\right|_{0}^{1} \\
  &  - \int_0^1 3\frac{\cos((n+1/2)\pi x)}{(n+1/2)\pi}dx \\
  &= \frac{3(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1/2)^2\pi^2}
\end{align}
I got instead : $$6\frac{(-1)^n-1}{(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}$$ . The first integral of that (dis)integration by parts is 0, and the second has upper and lower boundaries 1 and 0, so you should get $sin(n\pi+\pi/2)=cos(n\pi)|_0^1=((-1)^n-1)$. 6 comes from 2 from def.

Comment: That is, $2*3=6$, where 2 comes from the definitions of the Fourier integral. And at last, the minus sign in front of the last integral should be a plus,.